# Connect Android App with Server through WiFi with different subnets

Tags: android, http, webserver, ip, wifi

What I have: Android App, my Laptop.

My app send through httpget some values, for example: `http://ipaddress/receive?value1=1`

I have a webserver that runs on my laptop to listen this http requests.

I connect my laptop and phone through WiFi:

1)WiFi connecting.

2)I run the browser, it open the security page with http address. I write my login and pass, it redirects me to  https, that says Connection Succesfull. Now I have access to the  Internet.

My phone get IP: xxx.xxx.147.139

My laptop get IP: xxx.xxx.146.177

*xxx - are the same.

When I send request from my browser on laptop - my server read it good. When I'm trying to make http get from phone (http://xxx.xxx.146.177/receive?value1=1 - I use my laptops IP) it isn't working.

I understand that I have different subnets (Am I right?) and my httpget cannot be done.

What can I do in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Set the server to allow anonymous connection and check your manifest permissions.

Comment: What kind of permissions should I have? I use only Internet Permission.

Comment: Thats all you should need on the android side.  Maybe something with your router..?

Comment: I have no access to the router or something that is connected with WiFi...Can it be with HTTPS connected? From local maschine i use http and it works. Bur who knows...